# Port forwarding with a split tunnel VPN on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, iptables

I'm trying to accept incoming connections to port `20983` on my VPN connection `tun0`.  Right now split tunneling is working correctly, sending all data from user `vpn` through `tun0`.  I've configured the port with the VPN provider but am not able to successfully accept connections.

This is my OpenVPN `up.sh` file.

```
#! /bin/bash

export INTERFACE="tun0"
export VPNUSER="vpn"
export LOCALIP="192.168.1.2"
export LOCALSUB="192.168.1.0/24"
export NETIF="eno1"

# flushes all the iptables rules, if you have other rules to use then add them into the script
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -F -t mangle
iptables -F -t filter

# my custom firewall rules.  Needed for ssh, etc.
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#SSH
iptables -A INPUT -s $LOCALSUB -i $NETIF -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT ! -s $LOCALIP -o $NETIF -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j REJECT

# mark packets from $VPNUSER
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! --dest $LOCALIP -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT --dest $LOCALIP -p udp --dport 53 -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT --dest $LOCALIP -p tcp --dport 53 -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! --src $LOCALIP -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --save-mark

# allow responses
iptables -A INPUT -i $INTERFACE -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# let $VPNUSER access lo and $INTERFACE
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $INTERFACE -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j ACCEPT

# all packets on $INTERFACE needs to be masqueraded
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $INTERFACE -j MASQUERADE

# allow forwarded ports
iptables -A INPUT -i $INTERFACE -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 20983 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $INTERFACE -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 20983 -j ACCEPT

# allow IPv4 forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Start routing script
/etc/openvpn/routing.sh

exit 0
```

This is the output of `iptables -S`.

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eno1 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 20983 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 20983 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -s 192.168.1.2/32 -o eno1 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: is this your vpn server or a client?  is client to client enabled on the server side? is there something listening on that port? what interface is it listening on? is forwarding enabled for your interfaces? did you mean port 20983 instead of 12345? there are no port 12345 entries on your iptables output.

Comment: This is on my client.  I've got a torrent client listening on that port.  Forwarding is enabled, I added that line to the "up.sh" example.  I corrected the port to 20983.